# Bad magic number in super-block : Red Hat 6

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I extended a disk on RHEL 6.9. I am getting superblock error when running resize2fs on the new disk.

This was the previous filesystem layout before resizing:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 289.9 GB, 289910292480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 35246 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005b727

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1       24316   195311616   83  Linux
```

This is the filesystem layout after resizing

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 289.9 GB, 289910292480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 35246 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005b727

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1       35246   283113463+  83  Linux
```

I deleted the partition /dev/sdc1 only and recreated to extend to the rest of space, I did not write a filesystem on it as we have data on it.

When resizing the filesystem i am getting the error below.

```
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I ran the below steps:

> Run fdisk on the right disk (X is the correct letter of your disk):
>
> `fdisk /dev/sdX`
>
> Check the partition table by pressing `p` (to view partition details)
>
> Delete the partition by pressing d (to delete the partition)
>
> Select the right partition that you want to delete, in most cases will
> be the only on the disk, so press `1` (to select the partition)
>
> Create a new partition by pressing `n` (to create a new partition) and
> select the partition type whether Primary (by pressing `p`) and the
> right number
>
> Get the first block from the partition details in point 2 Press enter
> to accept the default as the last block.
>
> Check the partition table by pressing `p` (to list the partition and
> confirm) Save your new partition table Finally, you need to re-read
> the partition table using this command:
>
> `[root@linux ~]# partprobe`
>
> Your partition resize is now completed. Note that the partition that
> you want to resize must be the last one on disk so it can grow
> contiguously into the free space.
>
> Now it’s the turn of the filesystem inside the partition: you also
> need to resize it on the extended partition.
>
> First could be useful to check the filesystem. Then you can resize it
> and this can vary on the filesystem type. For ext3 and ext4 you can
> use this command:
>
> ```
> [root@linux ~]# resize2fs /dev/sdX
> linux linux-kernel filesystems ext4 parted
> ```

Please advise how i can resolve this ?

Comment: Dumb, question. But this is EXT4 right? Can you try running `file -s /dev/sdc1` and checking the filesystem format?

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling you're assuming its an EXT4 partition and its probably not. You can use a filesystem agnostic option which should work instead.

```
fsadm resize /dev/sdc1
```

This should detect and resize no matter the filesystem (provided its one of the common filesystem types).
Other than that you can run `file -s /dev/sdc1` to see what actual filesystem it is.